# How can I add a field in Entityform / hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to add a field to the form in hook_form_alter. What's the proper way of adding fields in this hook in case of entityform?

I tried to add it this way:

```
$form['leadname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 'abc'
);
```

but I have the impression that this is not the way it should be done...

Answer (score 0):

That is the way it should be done.

For example using

```
MODULE_form_ENTITYFORM_MACHINE_NAME_entityform_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the following API's

- [**field_create_field**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) : Creates a field.
- [**field_create_instance**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) : Creates an instance of a field, binding it to a bundle.
- [**field_delete_field**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7) : Marks a field and its instances and data for deletion.
- **[field_delete_instance](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_instance/7)** : Marks a field instance and its data for deletion.

Reference

- [Programmatically create a field in Drupal 7](https://smbjorklund.no/how-programmatically-create-field-drupal-7)

Comment: This is not what the they asked.